# Cómo hacer un formulario que rellene un PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, datatable

Hay alguna forma en la que pueda hacer desde una vista de formulario que envíe datos a un documento pdf con Ruby on Rails?

Estoy usando `gem 'wicked_pdf'` y `gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'`
Pero hasta el momento sólo he conseguido traer datos de una base de datos a una tabla en mi pdf, lo que busco más bien es seleccionar datos de una tabla y solo ellos imprimirlas en un pdf

Agradecería muchisimo cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar!!

Comment: ¿y donde está tu template `devices/entrega`?, deberías en tu index llamar a `@devices = Device.where(id: params[: device_ids ]` para cargar solo los equipos que necesitas. ¿que es específicamente lo que no te funciona? ¿algún error que te esté arrojando?

Comment: El template está en App/Views/Devices/entrega.pdf.erb
Disculpa, tampoco me expliqué muy bien; en mi index necesito cargar todos los equipos que tengo en mi tabla, de los cuales yo seleccionaré cuales quiero entregar, después eso lo paso a otra vista de edición que es edit_multiple.html.haml en donde introduciré en un formulario los datos que voy a actualizar mediante def update_multiple.

Lo que requiero hacer es tomar los datos del formulario y pasarlos a un pdf, lo que tengo ahora es la integración en el documento pero de toda la tabla a través de http://localhost:3000/devices.pdf

Answer (score 0):

lo que yo te recomendaría sería crear un controlador que reciba la información de tu formulario y después renderice el PDF. El siguiente método iría en tu controlador:

```
def generate_pdf
  # acá sacas la información del formulario, por ejemplo:
  @campo1 = params[:campo1]

  respond_to do |format|
    render pdf: ...
  end
end
```

Tienes que crear la vista de este controlador (con el contenido del PDF) y la ruta en routes.